# Iterating through every other element within list recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, recursion

I have been trying to figure out a clear and concise method to iterate through elements in a list in a form of recursive loop.

For example, if I have a list:

```
My_list = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

I would like to extract every other element from the list.

```
New_list = [2, 6, 10, 14, 18]
```

I then want to take the discarded values and take every second of those. And so on, recursively.

Since my first run through the list ended at 18, I will skip over 20 and go back to the beginning of the list as I want to extract every other elements.

```
My_list = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]

# Elements not been used after first operation = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]

New_list = [2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 4, 12, 20, 8, 16]  # desired output
```

What methods can I use to loop within a list?

Comment: Have you written some code that we can look at?

Comment: `My_list[::2]` ....

Comment: Do you also need to extract a list for `Elements not been used` ? Is `[2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 4, 12, 20, 16, 8]` your desired output?

Comment: @jpp yes I already know how to extract every two elements but it is my goal to loop over the list and extract again from elements not been used. Indeed [2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 4, 12, 20, 16, 8] is my desired output

Comment: @JBernardo yes I am aware of the method of extracting every other two elements, but would there be a way to loop through the list again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `while` loop with a generator:

```
L = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]

def recursive_odds(x):
    while x:
        yield from x[::2]
        x = x[1::2]

res = list(recursive_odds(L))

[2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 4, 12, 20, 8, 16]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use python's really cool slicing syntax:

`new_list=my_list[::2]`

to get every other element.

It means `new_list` is `my_list` from the begining to the end with a stride of 2

then your ramainder elements are `elements_not_used = [item for item in my_list if item not in new_list]` and you can just continue until `len(my_list)<2`

Comment: This doesn't actually answer OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

using while loop you can do this:

```
final=[]
while len(mylist)>0:
     final.extend(mylist[::2])
     mylist=mylist[1::2]
print(final)
```